# Why Core data needs? How to implement it?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, core-data-migration

- What is the need of Core Data in iPhone development?
- What are the steps to implement it?
- What is mean by validating, migration in Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been watching this question for a while, and since no one has jumped in with an answer I thought I'd give it a shot to get you started (if you haven't already google'd yet). I'm a coredata (and iphone app development) newbie too, here are the resources that I used to get me started:

The Stanford iPhone App course: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225 has a good CoreData aspect to it, as part of the Paparazi series of assignments.

with slides here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter

As you probably know, the iPhone Developer space has a lot of tutorials and sample code here:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/

And, this tutorial looks quite thorough:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_OS_Core_Data_Tutorial

I know I'm not answering your question (especially relating to Migration), and since you asked over a week ago you've probably google'd it yourself - but hopefully a couple of these resources help you out as they helped me.